# OS X git pull error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: git, macos

So there are plenty of resources for this error message, and none of the solutions given worked for me. I don't know if it is an OS X issue or what, but I ended up having to create an entirely new repo as my temporary solution. I tried to run `git pull` in the OS X (El Capitan) Terminal app (bash shell) and got the message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:    
[list/of/changed/files]
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. Aborting
```

Here are some things I tried which didn't work:

```
git reset --hard
git stash save --keep-index
git pull -f
git clean -fd
git checkout -f master
```

Here is the output of `git status` (note that none of these are files I actually changed):

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 130 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest1
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest1.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest1.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest2
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest2.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest2.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest3
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest3.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest3.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest4
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest4.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/cardtest4.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest1
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest1.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest1.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest2
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest2.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest2.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest3
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest3.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest3.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest4
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest4.gcda
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittest4.gcno
modified:   projects/profiod/teammate2Dominion/unittestresults.out

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Show us the output of `git status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `git stash;git pull --rebase ; git stash pop`